# get around using break or return statements

Tags: matlab, conditional-statements

I am using Matlab to modify some code that will be used in a real time system.  The real time system can't use 'break' or 'return' statements.  I have a bunch of for loops in Matlab that use 'break' or 'return'.

This is an example:

```
for j = find(vec == 0)
   if A(j) == 1
      break;
   end
end
```

How do I get around using the 'break' statements?  I was told that I can use a 'while' loop instead.  however, I am trying to see if there are other ways.
This seems like it should be a basic question but I can't think of other solutions right now.

Comment: When you are stating `j = find(vec == 0)`, you are using `j` as a vector and not as an iterator. Are you sure you want that?

Comment: @Divakar Well, now I got your idea. It's unlikely OP makes a mistake here, or otherwise he/she will run into another problem.

Comment: Or just tell us what you plan to achieve with such a code.

Answer (score 0):

A `for` with `break` is equivalent to a `while`.

```
for jj = find(vec == 0)
   if A(jj) == 1
      break;
   end
end
```

....

```
ind = find(vec == 0);
p = 1;
while ( A(ind(p)) ~= 1 && p<length(ind) )
    p = p+1;
end
p = ind(p);
```

bonus: using `i` and `j` is bad: [Using i and j as variables in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab)

Comment: Hopefully `OP` will start talking to clear out what he/she really wants out of all these.